# Visual Studio error when adding .accdb datasource

Tags: .net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, oledb

Im trying to add an access database as a OLEDB datasource in my C#.net Windows Form App.

Heres the error: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed".

Configuration:
Windows 8 X64
Microsoft Office 2013 X32
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1

Through searching forums and etc, I have installed the following drivers based on other suggestions:
Installed Microsoft Access Database Engine (2010)
Installed Microsoft Access Database Engine (2007)
Installed Microsoft Access Runtime 2007

What could I be missing?

Comment: I had this problem with OleDb ages ago and found out that it was being caused by a redundant node in my DbProviderFactories section of my machine.config file. Does the answer marked green in this thread (http://forums.asp.net/t/1853393.aspx?Unable+to+find+the+requested+Net+Framework+Data+Provider+It+may+not+be+installed+) help you at all?

Comment: I dont have a redundant node; however, I noticed that the only DBProviderFactories sub node i had was for SQL Server Compact and IBM DB2. Should I also have one for OleDB?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver? 
You probably use that engine, try to install it.

I believe it will help you, let me know.

Comment: I believe it is installed, as i have gone through and installed the MS Access Database Engine 2007-2010. Is there a solid way to check?

Comment: Whats the connection String you're using?

Comment: Im using the data connection wizard -- however, when i click advanced, the connection string field is blank

Comment: Try to insert this line: 
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=FullPathTOFile\YourFile.accdb;
if the database has password, add: Jet OLEDB:Database Password=yourPass; (right after the semi-colon)

Comment: Added it; but still same error -- Unable to find the requested .NET Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.